# Objective-C defining the same category in multiple modules

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I have 2 categories defined in 2 modules:

```
Module 1: 

Array2D+RawString.m: 

@implementation Array2D(RawString) 

+ (Array2D *)arrayWithRawString {
  // some implementation specific to module 1
}

@end

Module 2: 

Array2D+RawString.m: 

@implementation Array2D(RawString) 

+ (Array2D *)arrayWithRawString {
  // some implementation specific to module 2
}

@end
```

Both categories are visible only within its own module. What I expect is that, the code in module 1 will the file in module 1, and vise versa.

However, what I have notice is that the module 2's implementation is actually overridden by module 1. Why is it so? How do I deal with this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's so because that's the way the language defines it. If you define a category with the same name in two places, the compiler/linker will randomly pick one of them.

You can have categories with different names. Just don't call them both RawString.

Comment: sigh, i use categories all over the place. had to do a file dedup then

Comment: Just to add to this that the method names defined by your categories also need to be unique, if they have different implementations. The visibility of the category to the sender does not mean that the object does not respond to the message defined by the category. Meaning that as soon as your Array2D(RawString) category is loaded, all Array2D instances will now respond to the selector arrayWithRawString. So even if you have two categories with distinct names, the implementations would still be in (I'm assuming) a last-man-wins scenario because they are not unique names.

Comment: @John The category names do no matter (as BenW says).  The method names are all that matters.